# How to check NameNode in Cloudera Terminal?

Tags: hadoop

Which command should we use to get all Name Node and secondary Name Node total details in Cloudera terminal?

Comment: What do you mean by `get all Name Node,secondary Name Node total details in cloudera terminal`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dfsadmin command](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/commands_manual.html#dfsadmin)

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```